# Why does emacs dired not display the same files as the Windows "Explorer" (e.g. Windows/System32/config)

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

(Emacs 24.3.1 i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601 of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN)

Emacs dired of `C:Windows/System32/config` displays only the directories:

- '..'
- 'systemprofile'
- '.'
- 'TxR'
- 'RegBack'
- 'Journal'

in the directory.

Windows Explorer displays 33 other files, mostly ".LOG", ".LOG1" or ".LOG2" files, but also

- SOFTWARE
- DEFAULT
- SYSTEM
- SAM
- BCD-Template
- COMPONENTS{[hash]}
- ...

My original suspicion was that the content of that directory is accurately displayed by dired (i.e. the files are not really there) but a cygwin ls -al shows the files that dired does not display. Is this one of Windows7 misdirections or is my Emacs config wrong or ...?

Comment: Is `dired-omit-mode` turned on? If so, what are the values of options `dired-omit-files` and `dired-omit-extensions`? What is the value of `dired-listing-switches`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Dired-ls.html)

> Dired uses an internal lisp implementation of ls by default on
>   Windows. For consistent display of symbolic links and other
>   information with other programs (eg Cygwin) and performance reasons,
>   you may want to use a Windows port of ls instead.
>
> ```
> (setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program t)      ;; use external ls
> (setq insert-directory-program "c:/cygwin/bin/ls") ;; ls program name
> ```